# Flutter emulator Mouse region not detected

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the same code from Documentation for MouseRegion but I cannot get any feedback on entering or exiting the container.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MouseRegion-class.html

Comment: Are you running it on mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MouseRegion does not register entering or exiting in mobile because you are not hovering over it, you can press on it and that it registers, but you are not "entering" it, if you run the code on the web, it should work the way you want it to.